# why .lck file is created when performing remote command using expect4j？

Tags: java, linux, ssh, locking

I'm using Expect4j to perform remote command to a host. The command is

```
/usr/openv/volmgr/bin/tpconfig -add  -application_server mongodb1-27017 -application_type mongodb -host_user_id root -host_password rootroot -host_RSA_key 2acff30394f95f9576e9b4c82c1aa6efff0a648b0df246a4a3aefb0c263b7268 -requiredport 27017 -application_server_conf /usr/openv/var/global/mongodb1:27017.txt
```

In short, the command is

```
tpconifg -someoperate fileName
```

When I send the command via Expect4j it creates a `.lck` file. Why? And how can I avoid it?

[image: lck file created]

Comment: Why do you want to avoid this? Lock files are used to control access to resources and these are probably important to the function of the tool you're using.

Comment: yes，the lck file is useful.I have sovled the problem,because the tpconfig process ocassionally crashed,the lck file is leaved over and never be delelted.So I could ensure the tpconfig command executed correctly and avoid to leave the lck file.